# PushSharp Library and sending notifications to APN

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I've downloaded the library [Push Sharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/) and checked through the source and I couldn't figure out how to start sending notifricatinos to APN.

As given in their documentation I've configured the certificate of Apple. But the library is too complex and couldn't figure out where to start. Even the project is loaded in my VS2010 with loads of errors. Is it something to do with VS2010?

Can someone please point me to a beginner level resource which will help me to get started with Push Sharp. I'm pulling my hair off for last couple of days. Hope someone would be able to help me out.

Comment: The Push# [documentation](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/blob/master/Documentation/) sort of [has an example](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/blob/master/Documentation/APNS-Guide-Images/apns-guide-022.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For beginner level, below link is best to start up :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Comment: Thanks it kinda helped. But not directly relevant to question.

Comment: @MJM you can always set [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18019149/7724) as the accepted instead.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you're still looking, but this (hopefully) seems to be almost exactly what you're looking for: [Send push notifications to iPhone with PushSharp, C#, MonoTouch, client-side and server-side](http://woutercx.com/2013/05/09/sending-push-notifications-iphone-with-pushsharp-csharp-monotouch-client-server-side/)

Code excerpt:

```
_pushBroker = new PushBroker();
var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes("PushSharp.PushCert.Development.p12");
_pushBroker.RegisterAppleService(
  new ApplePushChannelSettings(false, appleCert, "ThePassword")); 
_pushBroker.QueueNotification(
  new AppleNotification()
  .ForDeviceToken(deviceToken)
  .WithAlert(message)
  .WithBadge(1)
  .WithSound("sound.caf"));
```

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.